# I need to multiply and sum one list, the output should be like this

Tags: prolog

I need to multiply and sum one list, the output should be like this:

```
?- tp4([1,7,0,1,2,3,5], L).
L = [210,19,1,7,0,1,2,3,5]
```

First the multi, next the sum and at the end the rest of the numbers.

Comment: Take a look at maplist/2 and foldl/4.

Comment: Im new at prolog what you mean maplist/2 and foldI/4?

Comment: They are the meta-predicates you need (actually just foldl/4) (if your Prolog has it). Check it out: [foldl README](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/swipl_notes/about_foldl/README.md)

Comment: This seems to be an exercise on proper structuring of list arguments. Do you already have list_sum/2 and list_mul/2 ? Then just provide those results in the head of tp4/2

Comment: Shouldn't the result be instead `[0,19,1,7,0,1,2,3,5]`? There's a zero in the middle of the list...

Comment: no, multipl([], 1).
multipl([H|T], L):-H=\=0, multipl(T, X), L is X * H.
multipl([H|T], L):-H=:=0, multipl(T, X), L is X.
 if there is a 0 the program dont multiply

Answer (score 3):

Here is a builing brick answer to your question since you seem to have a "where to start" problem. It is important to learn it by yourself, therefore you can conclude the correct answer by using [maplist/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/2) and [fold/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=foldl/4) as mentioned from [David Tonhofer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884463/david-tonhofer). But these are "advanced" predicates, so lets start from scratch and implement the base functionalities.

First: how to append elements to a list. You can either put something as a head of a list (`[Head|List]`) or use the predicate `append/2` (which is build in but you can easily implement it by yourself). Note that variables start with a capital letter.

```
?- List=[1,2,3,4], Head = 0, Out=[Head|List].
Head = 0,
List = [1, 2, 3, 4],
Out = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

?- List2=[1,2,3,4], List1 = [0], append(List1,List2,Out).
List1 = [0],
List2 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
Out = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].
```

You are be able to add elements to a list.

If you want to implement your own predicate, which works on lists, you either use the inbuild predicates or implement it yourself. We'll do the second one for the example of subtraction (all elements are subtracted from the last element).

Our predicate `subtract/2` needs 2 attributes: a list (input) and a "return" value (output).

If the list has only one element (`[H]`), return the element. Otherwise split the list into a `Head` element and a `Rest` list (`[Head|Rest]`), compute the substract value for the list `Rest` (`Tmp`) and subtract `Head` from it:

```
subtract([H],[H]).
subtract([Head|Rest], Sub):-
    subtract(Rest,Tmp),
    Sub is Tmp - Head.
```

Test:

```
?- subtract([1,2,3,10],O).
O = 4 ;
false.
```

Works, not perfect but works. Now you know how to add elements to a list and have an example how to build predicated which operate on lists and use arithemtic functions. Now you can build your desired function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to walk the list and compute the product and sum as you go from element to element. Given the neutral elements of the product and sum are, respectively, `1` and `0`:

```
product_sum_list([Head| Tail], [Product, Sum, Head| Tail]) :-
    product_sum_list(Tail, Head, 1, Product, 0, Sum).
```

Note that we're requiring the list to have at least one element. The auxiliary `product_sum_list/6` performs the actual computation of the product and sum:

```
product_sum_list([], Last, Product0, Product, Sum0, Sum) :-
    Product is Product0 * Last,
    Sum is Sum0 + Last.
product_sum_list([Next| Tail], Current, Product0, Product, Sum0, Sum) :-
    Product1 is Product0 * Current,
    Sum1 is Sum0 + Current,
    product_sum_list(Tail, Next, Product1, Product, Sum1, Sum).
```

By splitting the list between its head tail moving the tail to the first argument of the auxiliary predicate, we take advantage of the first argument indexing provided by the generality of Prolog systems to avoid the creation of spurious choice-points.

Sample call:

```
| ?- product_sum_list([1,7,0,1,2,3,5], L). 

L = [0,19,1,7,0,1,2,3,5]

yes
```

You can achieve the same results using, as David suggested, meta-predicates for mapping and folding lists. But given that we need to compute **both** product and sum, the straight-forward solution is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Eu preciso que na multiplicação quando encontre o número 0 que passe para o próximo número, para o resoltado não ser 0.  O código que eu tenho até aqui é o seguinte : soma([],0).
soma([H|T], L):- soma(T, X), L is X + H.

multipl([], 1).
multipl([H|T], L):-H=\=0, multipl(T, X), L is X * H.
multipl([H|T], L):-H=:=0, multipl(T, X), L is X.


tp4([H|T],[multipl,soma,H|T]):-tp4

eu queria meter agora tudo numa lista, o resultado da multiplicação, a soma e a lista. M as não sei como o fazer.  @Paulo Moura

Comment: Edit the question with your code in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

A common Prolog idiom is the use of a *helper predicate*, that takes extra arguments that maintain state. These also help you get to *tail recursion* so as to not consume stack.

The naive way to multiply a list might be:

```
multiply( []     , 0 ) .  % The empty list has a product of zero.
multiply( [P]    , P ) .  % A list of length 1 is the value of the singleton element.
multiply( [N|Ns] , P ) :- % To compute the product of a list of length > 1...
  multiply(Ns,T),         % - recursively multiply the tail of the list, then 
  P is N * T              % - multiply the head by the product of the tail
  .                       % Easy!
```

Summation would be pretty much identical save for the operation involved.

[*Note:* given a list of sufficient length, this would eventually fail due to a stack overflow.]

Using a *helper predicate* (1) makes it *tail recursive*, meaning it won't blow up and die on a long list, and (2) will facilitate combining summation and multiplication. The 'helper' implementation looks like this:

```
multiply( []     , 0 ) .
multiply( [N|Ns] , P ) :- multiply(Ns,N,P).

multiply( []     , P , P ) .
multiply( [N|Ns] , T , P ) :-
  T1 is T * N ,
  multiply( Ns, T1, P )
  .
```

And summation, again, is pretty much identical.

Now we can combine them to get what you want:

```
multiply_and_sum( []     , [0,0]    ) .
multiply_and_sum( [N|Ns] , [P,S|Ns] ) :-
  multiply_and_sum( Ns, N, N, P, S )
  .

multiply_and_sum( []     , P, S, P, S ) .
multiply_and_sum( [N|Ns] , X, Y, P, S ) :-
  X1 is X * N,
  Y1 is Y + N,
  multiply_and_sum( Ns, X1, Y1, P , S )
  .
```